# UIActivityTypeMessage Supported Formats

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, uidocumentinteraction, imessage

What are the file format types supported by UIActivityTypeMessage in iOS7.0..

I am trying to create a recorder and hence want to share the audio recorded in the format .m4a using iMessage.

Kindly advice on what is the probable solution. Also note that i have tried using both UIActivityViewController and UIDocumentInteractionController but the iMessage option donot popup.

UIActivityViewController,

```
pathUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"m4a"]];

controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[pathUrl] applicationActivities:nil];
controller.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,UIActivityTypeAirDrop,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,UIActivityTypePrint,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

UIDocumentInteractionController,

```
interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:pathUrl];
interactionController.delegate = self;
[interactionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 160.0f, 200.0f) inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Comment: Have you checked that MMS or Facetime enabled in the device?

Comment: As per documentation, UIActivityTypeMessage
The object posts the provided content to the Messages app.
When using this service, you can provide NSString and NSAttributedString objects as data for the activity items. You may also specify NSURL objects whose contents use the sms scheme.
If MMS or FaceTime are enabled, you can provide UIImage, ALAsset, and NSURL objects as data for the activity items. You may also specify NSURL objects whose contents use the assets-library scheme.

Comment: I want to share using the share sheet and not using MFMailComposeViewController..